# Bundle identifier is missing - macOS 10.12 and Xcode 8 - 5.5.0.GA

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I updated to macOS 10.12 and Xcode 8 and cannot build to the App Store.  There are no changes other than Xcode 8 and macOS update.  I am using SDK 5.5.0.GA.

--

```
[ERROR] :  Error details: Bundle identifier is missing. MySlomins doesn't have a bundle identifier for the Release build configuration. Add a value for PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER in the build settings editor.
[ERROR] :  Error details: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

  Name                        = Mac OS X
  Version                     = 10.12
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 8
  Memory                      = 17179869184
Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 0.12.7
  npm Version                 = 2.11.3
Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.9
Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 5.5.0.GA
  SDK Path                    = /Users/ktucc/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.0.GA
  Target Platform             = iphone
Command
```

Answer (score 3):

Many people experienced this problem before when upgrading to Xcode 8 ([TIMOB-23518](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23518)) and the solution was mostly the same so far:

Please ensure that you have both `Titanium SDK 5.5.1` and `Appcelerator CLI 5.5.1` (same as 5.5.0 but with some more bug fixes) **or later**. Also make sure that the selected SDK is 5.5.1 and the `tiapp.xml` has `<sdk-version>5.5.1.GA</sdk-version>` as the selected SDK to build with.

Comment: As a note - I had the latest CLI and the latest SDK specified in tiapp.xml, but this did not work until I also ran `appc use latest`

Comment: The CLI can only be set using the CLI itself (see command above). The tiapp.xml only manages the SDK version. Happy that it works now!

Answer (score 2):

For my case i missed entering identifier.

For this go Project Settings -> General -> Identitiy -> Bundle Identifier type your identifier. it is like com.example.projectname

Plus you need re import your provision file to xcode.

Hope it helps.